# Activate style with if statements for anchor position

Tags: javascript, css, refresh, anchor, if-statement

I am a beginner and have searched thoroughly, finding not a solution for this problem.

I've written a code where a css style changes when you click on a link, such as the one below:

```
function spHome(){
    document.getElementById("btnHome2").style.background = "url(../images/btn_navHoverArrow.png) no-repeat center bottom";
    document.getElementById("btnAccount").style.background = "0";
}

function spAccount(){
    document.getElementById("btnHome2").style.background = "0";
    document.getElementById("btnAccount").style.background = "url(../images/btn_navHoverArrow.png) no-repeat center bottom";
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. The problem for me is that when I refresh the page, the click state is no longer active. Is there a code that can allow the function to stay active only when the user is at a certain anchor point of the page. For example, if we have an anchor location called **index.html#home**, the home button will be active and when **index.html#account** is clicked, the account button will stay on clicked even after page refresh.

The example below doesn't seem to be working on jsfiddle but it is fine on all browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/HZLVt/3/

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add href hashes and return false onclick to avoid page reloading

```
<a href="#home" onclick="spHome();return false" id="btnHome2" title="Home"></a>
```

You need to execute js at page load, check the url's hash, and put the button's state accordingly to the hash.

Using jQuery, it would be something like (not tested):

```
$(function() {

    if (document.location.hash == "#home")
        spHome()
    else
        if (document.location.hash == "#account")
            spAccount()
})
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can put that code on docuent event "load"

Comment: Hi jperelli, Thanks so much. This works perfectly. I applied the return false but it was making it go to only one anchor when refreshing the page; after removing it the code started working perfectly. Again thank you so much for this.